# C# - Call to Assembly.LoadFile(string) causes dll to be loaded twice

Tags: c#, dll

For some reason, the call to Assembly.LoadFile(string fileName) causes the DLL I'm loading to be loaded twice. My fileName parameter is an absolute path to the dll.

I've used processexplorer to determine that the LoadAddress for the two dlls are different, and then I used processmonitor to determine that the one line of code being executed causes the same call stack to be generated to the system, which is the loading of the dll. If it matters, I'm having a C# executable load a C++ dll.

Has anyone else encountered such errors? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions that do not include the problematic code they are referring to are frequently closed as off-topic.

Comment: Assembly.LoadFile is only for loading .NET CLR files, not C++ COM objects. Without an example we can't really tell you what you are doing wrong.